# Reading data from multiple tcp connection using QEventLoop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, tcp

I have a problem where I need to read data from many tcp connections (over ~200) and send them to another program. I found similar problem to mine here [Reading data from multiple tcp connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622000/reading-data-from-multiple-tcp-connection).

I consider using `QObject` which will be running in one separate thread (`QThread`), responsible for reading data, which would have an array of `QTcpSockets` for all connections and connect sockets' signals to slot - so I would have one slot for over ~200 sockets. (Basically I will be using a `QEventloop` which is built in `QThread`)

Is it good practice and will it be efficient, when comparing it to using something like pure select or epoll solution? (I cannot find exact informations about how this built-in `QEventLoop` handles events internally, is it using `select`, `poll` or maybe some other solution?)